Flutter Gherkin can not find the scenarios and the steps
I have used flutter gherkin to automate my app, in short, this is my scenario:
Feature: Counter
  The counter should be incremented when the button is pressed.

  Scenario: Counter increases when the button is pressed
    When I tap the "increment" button 10 times
    Then I expect the "counter" to be 10

and these are my step definitions:
class TapButtonNTimesStep extends When2WithWorld<String, int, FlutterWorld> {
  TapButtonNTimesStep()
      : super(
          StepDefinitionConfiguration()
            ..timeout = Duration(
              seconds: 10,
            ),
        );

  @override
  Future<void> executeStep(input1, input2) async {
    final locator = find.byValueKey(input1);
    for (var i = 0; i < input2; i += 1) {
      await FlutterDriverUtils.tap(world.driver, locator);
    }
    
  }

  @override
  Pattern get pattern => r"I tap the {string} button {int} times";
}
class ExpectTextToBe extends Then2WithWorld<String, int, FlutterWorld> {
  ExpectTextToBe()
      : super(
          StepDefinitionConfiguration()
            ..timeout = const Duration(
              seconds: 10,
            ),
        );

  @override
  Future<void> executeStep(input1, input2) async {
    final textLocator = find.byValueKey(input1);
    expectMatch(world.driver!.getText(textLocator), input2.toString());
  }

  @override
  Pattern get pattern => r"I expect the {string} to be {int}";
}

also I have created an app.dart file that contains the void method and enables the flutterDriver:
void main() {
 
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();


  runApp(MyApp());
}

and finally, this is my app_test.dart file that configures the gherkin:
Future<void> main() {
  final config = FlutterTestConfiguration()
    ..features = [RegExp('features/*.*.feature')]
    ..reporters = [
      ProgressReporter(),
      TestRunSummaryReporter(),
    ]
    ..stepDefinitions = [
      TapButtonNTimesStep(),
      ExpectTextToBe(),
    ]
    ..restartAppBetweenScenarios = true
    ..targetAppPath = "test_driver/app.dart";
  return GherkinRunner().execute(config);
}

but when I run the command flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart I get below result:
    I/art     ( 6433): Debugger is no longer active
I/art     ( 6433): Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
I/flutter ( 6523): The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:35172/deuh4XiMY0g=/
0 scenario ()
0 step ()
0:00:00.000000
Terminating Flutter app under test

